# How to get a default Outlook folder from a second email address?

Tags: vba, email, outlook

There is a command for getting a default folder:

```
OutlookApplication.Session.GetDefaultFolder(x)
```

for example:

```
OutlookApplication.Session.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderOutbox)
```

The email user name isn't stated in the code, therefore it'll use the default Outlook user.

How do I work with both users, assuming I have two emails addresses linked to my Outlook account?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Loop though the stores in the `Namespace.Stores` collection and use `Store.GetDefaultFolder` instead.

Comment: Thank you very much for the help, I appreciate it, works like a charm.

Comment: Unfortunately I can't do that, since I dont have 15 reputation myself.

Comment: @YowE3K - Alright, did so then. Ty for the explanation.